# What is the German equivalent of the English phrase "Good Boy" or the most common/popular phrase used to praise a dog?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I am writing a novel and I need a one word/short phrase for the most common way an individual would praise a dog in German. Either the equivalent of the English phrase "Good Boy" or a popular alternative that a fluent German reader would recognize right away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is very difficult, if not impossible, to tell the "most common/popular" phrase.

In my opinion, an often heard phrase to praise a dog is

> Braver Hund!

Other possiblities would be

> Guter Hund!
>   Fein gemacht!

I think all would be recognized by a German speaker in that sense. I would prefer the first, but it's your decision, which you like best.

Comment: *Ei, guter Hund!*

Comment: Interestingly, both *fein* and *brav* are loan words of latinate origin (which also exist in English). Which begs the question: How did Germans praise their dogs in 1000 AD?

Comment: @DavidVogt What are the latin words for *fein* and *brav*?

Comment: @IQV You mean which words are they derived from? Old French *fin* and Spanish *bravo* or French *brave*, according to etymological dictionaries.

Comment: @DavidVogt Genau das war die Frage zu dem Kommentar. Ich hatte nur Schwierigkeiten den Bezug zu *subtilis* und *probus* herzustellen. Aber ich habe das jetzt so verstanden, dass er sich nicht auf "lateinische" Herkunft sondern eher "latinisierte" Herkunft bezieht.

Comment: @IQV Ich dachte, *latinate* könne *vom Lateinischen abgeleitet* bedeuten (insbesondere auch indirekt abgeleitet).

Comment: @DavidVogt "fein" hat zwar eine ähnliche Bedeutung in beiden Sprachen, aber "brav" (Deutsch) und "brave" (Englisch) haben verschiedene Bedeutungen.

Answer (score 3):

To *praise* dogs in German we usually use the phrases

> Guter Junge

or

> Gutes Mädchen

depending on the gender.